# Multhreading interrupt method call

Tags: java, multithreading

I write a java Thread interruption code but by call interrupt method,The exception generated but the thread didn't stopped.

```
public class MULTITHREADING_9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CHILD_THREAD childThread = new CHILD_THREAD();
        childThread.start();
        childThread.interrupt();

        System.out.println("MAIN_END");
    }

}
public class CHILD_THREAD extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("I'AM A LAZY THREAD");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("CHILD_THREAD_INTERRUPTED");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code is :-

```
MAIN_END
I'AM A LAZY THREAD
CHILD_THREAD_INTERRUPTED
I'AM A LAZY THREAD
I'AM A LAZY THREAD
I'AM A LAZY THREAD
I'AM A LAZY THREAD
```

Comment: The thread does not stop because you are catching the exception.

Comment: Interruption is little more than a messaging mechanism between threads. From Java Concurrency in Practice : "There is nothing in the API or language specification that ties interruption to any specific cancellation semantics". In other words : the task being interrupted needs to act in response to the interruption for the cancelation to function as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interrupt` method cause `InterruptedException` when your thread is sleeping. You should `return` from your method (or break the cycle - it depends on what you need) when you catch `InterruptedException` in order to stop the thread.
Also it's a good manners to check on every iteration whether your thread was interrupted by another one or not:
`Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`

Something like this:

```
public class CHILD_THREAD extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("CHILD_THREAD_INTERRUPTED");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("I'AM A LAZY THREAD");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("CHILD_THREAD_INTERRUPTED");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can put your cycle inside `try/catch` block:

```
public class CHILD_THREAD extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("CHILD_THREAD_INTERRUPTED");
                    return;
                }
                System.out.println("I'AM A LAZY THREAD");
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("CHILD_THREAD_INTERRUPTED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still have a doubt that if child thread get interrupted results in exception,why child thread is not stopped.

Comment: @LafhangaLadka because it just throws `InterruptedException` and you catch it in your `catch` block. Thread can't be stopped immediatly because it may holds any resources such as DB connection for instance. And in that catch block you have to close it properly before stop the current thread

Comment: @LafhangaLadka, interruption != stop because an interruption is just that - a signal to the thread. The thread has not been asked to stop.